# Creating more than 1 procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have a query with a couple of procedures, and i want to create them all at once when i execute the whole query but there are a couple o errors. The procedures are working fine if I create them one by one.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_GerarVoo @IDvoo nchar(7), @refAviao nchar(6), @IDrota nchar(6), @dataPartida datetime, @DuracaoHoras int, @PrecoC1 money, @PrecoC2 money, @PrecoC3 money AS
BEGIN
    declare @dataChegada datetime = (select DATEADD(HOUR, @DuracaoHoras, @dataPartida))

    INSERT INTO voo VALUES(@IDvoo, @dataPartida, @dataChegada, @refAviao, @IDrota, 0)

    INSERT INTO CustoLugar VALUES(@IDvoo, '1', @PrecoC1)
    INSERT INTO CustoLugar VALUES(@IDvoo, '2', @PrecoC2)
    INSERT INTO CustoLugar VALUES(@IDvoo, '3', @PrecoC3)

    declare @NumeroPassageiros int = (SELECT NT_passageiros FROM voo V JOIN aviao A ON V.refAviao = A.refAviao where IDvoo = @IDvoo)
    declare @i int = 1

    while @i <= @NumeroPassageiros
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @lugarBlt int = (select IDlugar from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IDLugar) as RowNum, * from lugar where refAviao = @refAviao ) lugar WHERE RowNum = @i) -- NAO COMEÇA DESDE O LUGAR 0
        INSERT INTO VendaVoo values(@IDvoo, @lugarBlt, 0)
        set @i = @i + 1 
    END
END

GO
-- |/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/|/| --
--                         PROCEDIMETO pr_Eliminar                           --
-- |\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\| --

CREATE PROCEDURE pr_EliminarVoo @IDvoo nchar(7) AS
BEGIN   
    IF((SELECT count(*) FROM vendaBilhete WHERE IDvoo = @IDvoo) > 0)
        Print 'Não é possivel eliminar o voo ' + @IDvoo
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        DELETE FROM voo WHERE IDvoo = @IDvoo
        Print 'O voo ' + @IDvoo + ' foi eliminado com sucesso'
        END
END
```

Sorry if some parts are in portuguese...

The errors are:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure pr_GerarVoo, Line 884
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure pr_GerarVoo, Line 884
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Line 884 is at the first 'BEGIN' after CREATE PROCEDURE pr_GerarVoo...

Comment: Without `go` or splitting into multiple files seems like the easiest way. `GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.` 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you are executing the script programmatically, you could use the [SMO `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0). This API recognizes `GO` batch terminators.